# How to open page in new tab/window?

Tags: google-app-maker

I need to perform something like `app.showPage(app.pages.%PAGENAME%)`but open the page in new tab.

Is it even possible in appmaker?

I am not opening an external link, I need to open the page of the app in a new tab.

Comment: I don't think you can do it directly, but the url will have the page name, `#?page=pagename`. You can  make a link button.

Comment: **Solution**: client property `app.buildUrl().__gwt_instance.a;` contains app's URL.

Not sure if a good practice, however it fulfilled my needs.

Comment: Consider posting that as a solution in the answer box below (with explanations, if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client property `app.buildUrl().__gwt_instance.a;` contains app's URL.

Not sure if a good practice, however it fulfilled my needs